# How do I control script execution time in PHP

Tags: php

for example I do have 5 PHP functions on a page which execute when loading. each functions has its own processing time and some of them take more time sometimes to complete the task. hence the total loading time of the said page is slow.

my question is how do I control execution time for each script and set time limit for the same. I am aware that there is an in built function in PHP called `set_time_limit();` but it gives fatal error if time is beyond the maximum limit...

Comment: What behaviour would you want to see if the time goes over the maximum? Should it log a message? Display an error?

Comment: no I dont want to see any error..the rest scripts needs to continue and display the result.

Comment: Isn't it doing that already? Taking it's own time to run and finally displaying the result?

Comment: Rather than getting inconsistent results by skipping functions, I'd look into alternative ways to get the work done. If, even after heavy optimizations, the work is such that it simply takes time, try to use cron jobs, queues, workers or similar patterns to separate the work from actual page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what your question says, I'm assuming that you have 5 functions in a single PHP file (script), executing, and if one of them executes for too long, it should be skipped.

The only way you can skip functions is to poll the time every once in a while.

```
function myFunction($someVar) {
    $startTime = time();
    $timeLimit = 10; // Let's say, time limit is 10 seconds
    while ($blah_blah == true) { // Some loop or code that takes a long time
        // Do some work
        if (time() - $startTime > $timeLimit) return; // Time's up!
    }
    // Done
    return;
}
```

Note that the function will only return at points where it checks if the time's up, and you have to manually place the points where you check if the time's up. This check does have some overhead, so try not to place it everywhere.

Please comment if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: what you mean by overhead?? is more a cpu intensive??

Comment: @mathew Of course, every additional operation takes more CPU time. If your loop executes many thousand times per second, the time comparison code will execute many thousand times per second as well, contributing a few fractions of a second each time.

Comment: Why bother with this? Using the error suppressor operator (`@`) behind the function call does the same.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to call `set_time_limit(0);` but that only works if you have `safe_mode` Off.

---

**My approach to this would be to use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php):**

```
function one() {
    register_shutdown_function('two');
    /* do stuff */
}

function two() {
    register_shutdown_function('three');
    /* do stuff */
}

function three() {
    /* do stuff */
}

one();
```

---

This doesn't seem to work with PHP 5.3.1, I guess it's because of the changes implemented in PHP 4.1.0:

> The shutdown functions are now called
>   as a part of the request. In earlier
>   versions under Apache, the registered
>   shutdown functions were called after
>   the request has been completed.

An alternative could be the use of [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php), or you can just **issue another request (with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for instance), and call [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) on the requested scripts**.